# Symfony 2, double error

Tags: forms, symfony, widget

Why i have double error when i want to customize my form ?

Template:

```
<div>
    {{ form_errors(edit_form.wiek) }}
    {{ form_widget(edit_form.wiek) }}   
</div>
```

HTML:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide us the input code ?

Comment: What do you need ? template, controller or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably see the error on the field level, but also on the form level. It can look like you have two errors especially if there's only one field in your form.

Dig into the [customizing error output](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#customizing-error-output) of the form cookbook for more details.

**Edit**

The doc gives a much better explanation :)

> *You can also customize the error output for just one specific field type. For example, certain errors that are more global to your form (i.e. not specific to just one field) are rendered separately, usually at the top of your form.*

Comment: No, i have only one field as you see below. I think that the widget also render the error but i don't know why.

Comment: Yes see my post : _especially if there's only one field in your form_.

Comment: Do you have a form_rest(edit_form) tag somewhere in your template ?

Comment: no i just create only form with one field to check. Why widget generate also errors ?